# How to install/run Python on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-snow-leopard

After giving up on doing a disk partition and getting Linux, I decided to try and install Python 3.3.2 on a 32 bit Intel Core 2 Duo iMac with OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. I did pretty much everything the [official website](http://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) says, but it isn't working at all.
First of all, I downloaded the installer for Mac OS X 6 and later, which should supposedly put a folder called MacPython 3.3 with IDLE, PythonLauncher and a Build Applet tool in my Applications folder. What I have instead is a folder called Python 3.3 which does contain (aside from the documentation and a command to update shell profile) IDLE and PythonLauncher, but no Build Applet tool; I typed 'python' into my Terminal window to see if 3.3.2 was installed, but it said Python 2.6.1 even after restarting my computer. The ReadMe in the disk image that contains the installer says running the installer should also 'put the underlying machinery into the folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework'. I did every search imaginable and apparently there is no such folder anywhere in my hard drive.
Basically, I want to install 3.3.2 and run things in programme mode rather than shell mode, which I find to be a huge pain in the bottom. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue18098 suggests that the Build Applet app has been removed in Python 3; the mention of it on the page you link to may be a documentation error.

Comment: What happens if you type `python3` into your terminal?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info! I'll try to find one for Python 3, if there are any available.

Comment: @SethMMorton It prints out 'Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 13:52:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.', so apparently it does recognise Python 3. I guess the next step would be learning some more Unix so I can actually set it as the default version of Python (I found the frameworks, by the way).

Comment: When execute the script, use `python3` instead of `python`.  Python is designed to have multiple versions installed, so you have to specify when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download or install any software.

Just write your code in your preferred text editor, and save it as a anything with `.py` at the end. Next, go to a terminal and type in `python *****.py`, where `*****` means whatever your file is named.

Answer (score -1):

Try typing 'idle python3.3' or something similar in the terminal.

Comment: IDLE takes files to open as command line arguments, not a python version to use, and OP already knows how to launch IDLE from Finder (and explicitly wants to avoid needing to use the Terminal). -1.

Comment: On the first point: okay, there should be a hyphen between the two words (I had a break from coding for a few weeks). On the second point: where does he actually say he managed to launch IDLE?